# Error with group by in inner query of correlated sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, group-by, correlated-subquery

I wrote the following query that is returning output without any error messages however I see an issue with the output:

```
select productid, productname, categoryid, unitprice
FROM production.products as PP
where unitprice in (select min(unitprice) as minprice 
                    from production.products as PC
                    group by categoryid)
order  by categoryid
go
```

Result:

```
24  Product QOGNU   1   4.50
3   Product IMEHJ   2   10.00
19  Product XKXDO   3   9.20
21  Product VJZZH   3   10.00
33  Product ASTMN   4   2.50
52  Product QSRXF   5   7.00
54  Product QAQRL   6   7.45
74  Product BKAZJ   7   10.00
13  Product POXFU   8   6.00
```

The output shows multiple rows for categoryid = 3. When we group by categoryid, shouldn't it show only one row (one min unit price) per categoryid.

Where am i going wrong?
Thanks in advance everyone for the help.

Comment: You are grouping only in the subquery. Also your `IN` compare with every price not the ones on the product category. Check Tim answer to see how use `JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not correlated.  You seem to intend:

```
select productid, productname, categoryid, unitprice
FROM production.products  p
where p.unitprice = (select min(p2.unitprice) as minprice 
                     from production.products p2
                     where p2.categoryid = p.categoryid
                    )
order by p.categoryid;
```

A `group by` does not a correlated subquery make.  A `where` (okay, sometimes `on` too) is needed.

Your specific query has a logic problem.  It gets any product whose price is the minimum price of any category -- even not its own.

I would write this as:

```
select p.productid, p.productname, p.categoryid, p.unitprice
from (select p.*,
             min(p.price) over (partition by p.categoryid) as minprice
      from production.products p
     ) p
where p.price = p.minprice
order by p.categoryid;
```

Note:  If multiple products all have the same minimum price, then this returns all of them.  If you specifically want one, then use `row_number()`:

```
select p.productid, p.productname, p.categoryid, p.unitprice
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by p.categoryid order by p.price asc) as seqnum
      from production.products p
     ) p
where seqnum = 1
order by p.categoryid;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current query is that the subquery of minimum prices is effectively a pool of *all* minimum prices, taken from every category.  But you really want to restrict your query to the minimum price for each respective category.  One approach is to instead join to your subquery, restricting the result set the way you want.

```
SELECT
    PP.productid,
    PP.productname,
    PP.categoryid,
    PP.unitprice
FROM production.products AS PP
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT categoryid, MIN(unitprice) AS minprice 
    FROM production.products
    GROUP BY categoryid
) t
    ON PP.categoryid = t.categoryid AND
       PP.unitprice  = t.minprice
ORDER BY categoryid
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. Now I know where I went wrong. Your answers have been very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get the min unit price for each category?

```
 SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT productid, productname, categoryid, unitprice,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY categoryid ORDER BY unitprice) AS ln
     FROM production.products as PP
 ) AS t WHERE t.ln=1
order  by categoryid
```